# Is there any online service to translate Vim commands to human readable form?

Tags: vim, vi

I found Vimmish:  http://dira.ro/2009/05/07/vimmish-vim-translator

A tool that translates Vim command sequences into human readable form:

Input:

```
iDon't know vim :(.<ESC>^2WBc2wbetter now<ESC><RIGHT>Da.<ESC>II can understan<ESC><RIGHT>~dE
```

Output:

```
                 i => insert before cursor:
Don't know vim :(. => type Don't know vim :(.
             <ESC> => go to normal mode
                 ^ => move to the begining of the line (not blank character)
                2W => move to the begining of the next space-separated word, 2 times
                 B => move backwards one space-separated-word
               c2w => change to the begining of the next word, 2 times
        better now => type better now
             <ESC> => go to normal mode
           <RIGHT> => move one character to the right
                 D => delete the rest of the current line
                 a => append after cursor:
                 . => type .
             <ESC> => go to normal mode
                 I => insert to the begining of the current line:
   I can understan => type I can understan
             <ESC> => go to normal mode
           <RIGHT> => move one character to the right
                 ~ => change character case
                dE => delete to the end of the next space-separated-word
```

It is programmed with Ruby.

¿Is there any online version of it, or something similar?

Comment: nice tool, seems it will be easy to create webapp from it

Comment: Some tool that works the other way around would be nice :)

Comment: I use one of those all the time.  I like to call it "Google". :)

Comment: Is it really common for people to provide you with a list of vi commands?  I've never had this happen...

Comment: I think it would be useful to understand some non-obvious mappings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

and here it is: [https://evangeneer.net/vim2human/#iDon't know vim :(.^2WBc2wbetter nowDa.II can understan~dE](https://evangeneer.net/vim2human/#iDon%27t%20know%20vim%20%3a%28.%3CESC%3E%5E2WBc2wbetter%20now%3CESC%3E%3CRIGHT%3EDa.%3CESC%3EII%20can%20understan%3CESC%3E%3CRIGHT%3E~dE)
you can POST a vin command to https://evangeneer.net/vim2human/ to get the text/plain version

Comment: bitrot is a nasty desease... evangeneer.net looks down from here

Comment: yeah, unfortunately I lost the wrapper code that I wrote there, and now I can't even find the original lib...
edit: it's there : https://github.com/dira/vimmish might try to do the wrapper again if I have 1 hour to play with this again